# How to create a telegram bot that checks user joined

Tags: bots, telegram

I am trying to create a bot that checks if a user has joined a channel and if it is true then reply an automatic message.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: StackOverflow is more oriented towards helping you fix a problem that you have run into while trying something. Just asking "How can I do this?" without providing an example of things that you have tried makes it seem like you want someone on the site to write your code for you. We would much rather help you when you hit a road block while coding.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [getChatMember](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchatmember) method with administer permission.

P.S. remember to put both `chat_id` and `user_id` into the request.

Comment: And it is possible that checks when I click an option?

Comment: @FrateGon Sure, you can do it when received Callback query